# Java Bit Operations: replacing nibble of hex

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have to write this code for a homework assignment but I don't even know where to start. Here is the javadoc to the method I have to write.

```
/**
* Sets a 4-bit nibble in an int

* Ints are made of eight bytes, numbered like so: 7777 6666 5555 4444 3333 2222 1111 0000
*
* For a graphical representation of this:
*   1 1 1 1 1 1                 
*   5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
* +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* |Nibble3|Nibble2|Nibble1|Nibble0|
* +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* 
* Examples:
*      setNibble(0xAAA5, 0x1, 0) //=> 0xAAA1
*      setNibble(0x56B2, 0xF, 3) //=> 0xF6B2
* 
* @param num int that will be modified
* @param nibble nibble to insert into the integer
* @param which determines which nibble gets modified - 0 for least significant nibble
*            
* @return the modified int
*/
```

Here is what I have. I've got it to work with the first example in the javadoc, But I know this does not hold true for all cases. Especially when int which != 0;

```
public static int setNibble(int num, int nibble, int which)
    {
    int newNibble = (num >> 4);
    newNibble = (newNibble << 4) | nibble;
    return newNibble;
    }
```

Should I be using shifts or not? I was told I could do this method in one line of code. 
Thanks for the help in advanced!

Comment: You should use shifts.

You are on the right track. Your current code will keep the original value and add the new nibble. You need to blank out the original nibble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you;

- extract the bits you want to keep by constructing a mask and using `&`
- place the bits to want to add into the right position with left shift `<<`
- combine them with bitwise OR

Comment: Clean and simple, a good answer.  The only bit I wanted to add is that while you can do _a lot of things_ in one line of code, depending on the readability of that line of code, it might not be worth the price in readability depending on your comfort level.  Still this question compacts to one line pretty nicely.

Comment: okay so for the example above with (0xAAA5, 0x1, 0) //=> 0xAAA1, to mask it I would use AAA5 & FFF0. Could I use an if statement to come up with that FFF0?

Comment: oh sorry. I meant a for with an if and else*

Comment: Hint: try `~0xF << 4 * which`

Comment: do you think you could help me with one more problem I'm having? I'm supposed to take in an int and retrieve the short from it. So I know that an int is 32 bit and a short is 16 so that there will be two parts of 16 in an int. So I would do ((int << 16) >> 16) to get the least significant 16 bit and (int >> 16) to get the most significant bit. But how would I do this if the input was a negative hex? For example: (getShort(0xFF254545, 1) //=> 0xFF25  where 1 represents the most significant 16 bit of the int.

Comment: I also know that if you use 0xFF254545L with the L for literal then it will show the value that I am wanting to get but how could I add the L at the end if that hex is being passed in as a parameter?

Comment: A short is also signed and the fact it is negative doesn't matter. You could use `(short)(i >> 16)` or `(short)(i >>> 16)` and they would do the same thing. To get the lower 16-bits you can do `(short) i`

Comment: You can pass `(int) 0xFF254545L` as an int value.